# "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted" when trying to make a raw HTTP POST to the "getchanges" endpoint

Tags: rest, getchanges, curl

I want to make a getchanges rest api request using an HTTP client. I am trying both curl and postman and unable to do this.

I'm trying to run this curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://192.16.11.133/_api/site/getchanges \
  -H 'Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "query": {
        "ChangeTokenEnd": null,
        "ChangeTokenStart": null,
        "DeleteObject": true,
        "Web": true,
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.ChangeQuery"
        }
    }
}'
```

But i keep getting 401 error for the **getchanges** endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

I am able to do NTLM with other rest endpoints fine. Example:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://192.16.11.133/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList \
  -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' \
  -H 'Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

So the NTLM auth is definitely authenticating me fine.

Why might I be getting this error for this HTTP Post?

The only way I can get the GetChanges api to work is from CSOM right now.

I'm guessing it wants me to go to a login endpoint, get cookies, then use the getchanges api, or to submit some other form input fields with it. or something.

Comment: Are you able to use other REST endpoints OK?

Comment: yeah. for example, the "get groups" rest api call works great. e.g. `{{sharepointURL}}/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the error:

> The security validation for this page is invalid and might be
>   corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your
>   operation again.

occurs  since `X-RequestDigest` header is missing in your example, it is *mandatory* to provide it for a `POST` request.

Refer, for example, [Writing data by using the REST interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints):

> Another important consideration when creating, updating, and deleting
>   SharePoint entities is that if you aren't using OAuth to authorize
>   your requests, these operations require the server's request form
>   digest value as the value of the X-RequestDigest header.

So, request form digest value needs to be requested first via the following request:

```
Url: http://<site url>/_api/contextinfo
Method: POST
```

Once `d:FormDigestValue` value is extracted from response, your request needs to be updated  by providing header:

```
-H 'X-RequestDigest: <value>'
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to come on here and comment, that is exactly why I had that error.